# Selecting from pandas dataframe (or numpy ndarray?) by criterion

Tags: numpy, pandas

I find myself coding this sort of pattern *a lot*:

```
tmp = <some operation>
result = tmp[<boolean expression>]
del tmp
```

...where `<boolean expression>` is to be understood as a boolean expression *involving* `tmp`.  (For the time being, `tmp` is always a pandas dataframe, but I suppose that the same pattern would show up if I were working with numpy ndarrays--not sure.)

For example:

```
tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']
result = tmp[tmp < 0]
del tmp
```

As one can guess from the `del tmp` at the end, the *only* reason for creating `tmp` at all is so that I can use a boolean expression involving it inside an indexing expression applied to it.

I would love to eliminate the need for this (otherwise useless) intermediate, but I don't know of any efficient<sup>1</sup> way to do this.  (Please, correct me if I'm wrong!)

As second best, I'd like to push off this pattern to some helper function.  The problem is finding a decent way to pass the `<boolean expression>` to it.  I can only think of indecent ones.  E.g.:

```
def filterobj(obj, criterion):
    return obj[eval(criterion % 'obj')]
```

This actually works<sup>2</sup>:

```
filterobj(df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II'], '%s < 0')

# Int
# 0     -1.650107
# 2     -0.718555
# 3     -1.725498
# 4     -0.306617
# Name: II
```

...but using `eval` always leaves me feeling all yukky 'n' stuff...  Please let me know if there's some other way.

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g., any approach I can think of involving the `filter` built-in is probably ineffiencient, since it would apply the criterion (some lambda function) by iterating, "in Python", over the panda (or numpy) object...

<sup>2</sup>The definition of `df` used in the last expression above would be something like this:

```
import itertools
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = ('A', 'B')
i = range(5)
ix = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(itertools.product(a, i)),
                               names=('Alpha', 'Int'))
c = ('I', 'II', 'III')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(len(idx), len(c)), index=ix, columns=c)
```

Comment: Just use `result`'s name as `tmp` ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the way Python works, I think this one's going to be tough.  I can only think of hacks which only get you part of the way there.  Something like

```
def filterobj(obj, fn):
    return obj[fn(obj)]

filterobj(df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II'], lambda x: x < 0)
```

should work, unless I've missed something.  Using lambdas this way is one of the usual tricks for delaying evaluation.

Thinking out loud: one could make a `this` object which isn't evaluated but just sticks around as an expression, something like

```
>>> this
this
>>> this < 3
this < 3
>>> df[this < 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-34-d5f1e0baecf9>", line 1, in <module>
    df[this < 3]
[...]
KeyError: u'no item named this < 3'
```

and then either special-case the treatment of `this` into pandas or still have a function like

```
def filterobj(obj, criterion):
    return obj[eval(str(criterion.subs({"this": "obj"})))]
```

(with enough work we could lose the `eval`, this is simply proof of concept) after which something like

```
>>> tmp = df["I"] + df["II"]
>>> tmp[tmp < 0]
Alpha  Int
A      4     -0.464487
B      3     -1.352535
       4     -1.678836
Dtype: float64
>>> filterobj(df["I"] + df["II"], this < 0)
Alpha  Int
A      4     -0.464487
B      3     -1.352535
       4     -1.678836
Dtype: float64
```

would work.  I'm not sure any of this is worth the headache, though, Python simply isn't very conducive to this style.

Comment: Reminds me of what they're trying to do replicating ggplot with Bokeh...not as straightforward as it is in R, it seems

Answer (score 1):

This is as concise as I could get:

```
(df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']).apply(lambda x: x if (x<0) else np.nan).dropna()

Int
0     -4.488312
1     -0.666710
2     -1.995535
Name: II
```