# Can one mimic lexical scoping with context managers?

Tags: python

In an [earlier post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986856) I asked about ways to avoid the intermediate `tmp` variable in patterns like:

```
tmp = <some operation>
result = tmp[<boolean expression>]
del tmp
```

...where `tmp` is a pandas object.  For example:

```
tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']
result = tmp[tmp < 0]
del tmp
```

The bee in my bonnet about this pattern basically comes from a longing for honest-to-goodness lexical scoping<sup>1</sup> that just won't die, even after years of programming Python.  In Python<sup>2</sup> I make do with explicit calls to `del`,

It occurs to me that it *may* be possible to use context managers to mimic lexical scoping in Python.  It would look something like this:

```
with my(df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']) as tmp:
    result = tmp[tmp < 0]
```

To be able to mimic lexical scoping, the context manager class would need to have a way to `del`ete the variable in the calling scope that gets assigned the value returned by its (the context manager's) '**enter**' method.

For example, with a generous dose of cheating:

```
import contextlib as cl

# herein lies the rub...
def deletelexical():
    try: del globals()['h']
    except: pass

@cl.contextmanager
def my(obj):
    try: yield obj
    finally: deletelexical()

with my(2+2) as h:
    print h
try:
    print h
except NameError, e:
    print '%s: %s' % (type(e).__name__, e)
# 4
# Name error: name 'h' is not defined
```

Of course, the problem is to implement `deletelexical` for real.  Can it be done?

Edit: As abarnert pointed out, if there had been a pre-existing `tmp` in the surrounding scope, `deletelexical` would not restore it, so it could hardly be regarded as an emulation of lexical scoping.  The correct implementation would have to save any existing `tmp` variables in the surrounding scope, and replace them at the end of the with-statement.

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g., in Perl, I would have coded the above with something like:

```
my $result = do {
    my $tmp = $df->xs('A')['II'] - $df->xs('B')['II'];
    $tmp[$tmp < 0]
};
```

or in JavaScript:

```
var result = function () {
    var tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II'];
    return tmp[tmp < 0];
}();
```

Edit: In response to abarnert's post & comment: yes, in Python one could define

```
def tmpfn():
    tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']
    return tmp[tmp < 0]
```

...and this would indeed prevent cluttering the namespace with the henceforth useless name `tmp`, but it does so by cluttering the namespace with the henceforth useless name `tmpfn`.  JavaScript (and Perl also, BTW, among others) allows ***anonymous*** functions, while Python doesn't.  In any case, I consider JavaScript's anonymous functions as a somewhat cumbersome way to get lexical scoping; it's certainly better than nothing, and I use it heavily, but it's nowhere near as nice as Perl's (and by the latter I mean not only Perl's `do` statement, but also the various other ways it provides to control scope, both lexical and dynamic).

<sup>2</sup>I don't need to be reminded of the fact that only an infinitesimally small fraction of Python programmers give a rat's tail about lexical scoping.

Comment: Looks a lot like [Getting the block of commands that are to be executed in the with statement](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12485837)

Comment: I don't think you can, at least not without getting so deeply into hack-and-implementation-details territory that it's not worth it. Btw, Python does lexical scoping, you just want a finer-grained way to introduce new scopes.

Comment: First, in JS, you're just defining a local function and calling it, which allows you to use the local function's scope. You can do the exact same thing in Python. So, what's wrong with that? Do you object to giving the function a name?

Comment: Second, you're showing an example of perl and JS syntax that frees everything defined _within_ the scope, but then trying to build Python syntax that leaves everything defined within the scope alone, but frees a specific thing defined outside the scope. It's more of like a `let` statement with an implicit `nonlocal everything-else` inside of it, or a C++ scope-guard macro, than a real lexical scope. Is that really what you want? (Also, what should happen if you already had a global named `tmp` before this `with` statement? And what should happen if you had a _local_ named `tmp`?)

Comment: It seems like a context manager that just restored `globals` and/or `locals` (or possibly just removed any newly-defined names from either/both, while allowing already-existing-but-rebound names to stay rebound?) is a better fit for what you're asking for, and may be not nearly as hard. Or, even more simply, a way to execute some arbitrary code with a temporary `globals` and/or `locals` (empty, copied from the surrounding, or explicitly passed in)?

Comment: @abarnert Are you thinking of `exec "tmp = ..." in some-dict`? I don't think it would be a good idea.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Well, I was thinking of passing `exec()` a code object rather than a string to be compiled, if there's a way to get the relevant code object. But the point isn't that it's a good idea, it's that it's what the OP seems to actually want, even though it's not what he's asking for.

Answer (score 3):

In your JavaScript equivalent, you do this:

```
var result = function () {
    var tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II'];
    return tmp[tmp < 0];
}();
```

In other words, in order to get an extra lexical scope, you're creating a new local function and using its scope. You can do the exact same thing in Python:

```
def tmpf():
    tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']
    return tmp[tmp < 0]
result = tmpf()
```

And it has the exact same effect.

And that effect isn't what you seem to think it is. Going out of scope just means it's garbage that can be collected. That's exactly what a real lexical scope would give you, but it's not what you want (a way to deterministically destroy something at some point). Yes, it happens to usually do what you want in CPython 2.7, but that's not a language feature, it's an implementation detail.

But your idea adds some more problems on top of the problem with just using a function.

Your idea leaves everything defined or rebound within the `with` statement changed. The JS equivalent doesn't do that. What you're talking about is more like a C++ scope-guard macro than a `let` statement. (Some impure languages allow you to `set!`-bind new names within a `let` that will live on outside the `let`, and you could describe this as a lexical scope with an implicit `nonlocal everything-but-the-let-names` inside the body, but it's still pretty weird. Especially in a language that already has a strong distinction between rebinding and mutating.)

Also, if you already had a global with the same name `tmp`, this `with` statement would erase it. That's not what a `let` statement, or any other common form of lexical scoping, does. (And what if `tmp` were a local rather than global variable?)

If you want to simulate lexical scoping with a context manager, what you really need is a context manager that restores `globals` and/or `locals` on exit. Or maybe just a way to execute arbitrary code inside a temporary `globals` and/or `locals`. (I'm not sure if this is possible, but you get the idea—like getting the body of the `with` as a `code` object and passing it to `exec`.)

Or, if you want to allow rebinding to escape the scope, but not new bindings, walk the `globals` and/or `locals` and delete everything new.

Or, if you want to just delete a specific thing, just write a `deleting` context manager:

```
with deleting('tmp'):
    tmp = df.xs('A')['II'] - df.xs('B')['II']
    result = tmp[tmp < 0]
```

There's no reason to push the expression into the `with` statement and try to figure out what it gets bound to.